# MERGE update with duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, sql-merge

I am trying to UPDATE target table but in source table I have duplicate data. I am trying in Azure SQL Server database. All will be ok with HASHBYTES but if I remove HASHBYTES it will raise an error:

```
drop table if exists #source
drop table if exists #target

CREATE TABLE #target(id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  a int NOT NULL,
  b int NOT NULL,
  c varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  d decimal(10,3) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id))

CREATE TABLE #source(a int NOT NULL,
  b int NOT NULL,
  c varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  d decimal(10,3) NULL)
INSERT #target (a, b, c, d) VALUES (1, 1, 'TEXT', NULL)
INSERT #source (a, b, c, d) VALUES (2, 2, 'TEST1', NULL), (2, 2, 'TEST2', NULL)
go

select a, b, count(*) as NumberOfRows
from #source
group by a, b
having count(*)>1

MERGE #target t
USING #source s ON t.a = s.a AND t.b = s.b
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
   INSERT (a, b, c, d) VALUES(s.a, s.b, s.c, s.d)
WHEN MATCHED and hashbytes('SHA2_512', CONCAT(t.c, t.d)) != hashbytes('SHA2_512', CONCAT(s.c, s.d))
THEN UPDATE
   set t.c=s.c
   , t.d=s.d 
;

select * from #target
```

I expect to have an error when source contain duplicate data.
When you run code first time all will be good, but when you ran MERGE again with HASHBYTES you need to have an error.
With HASHBYTES function MERGE execute successful without error:

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

Do you know why I don't get error with HASHBYTES function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why use `HASHBYTES` at all, why not just `WHEN MATCHED AND (t.c IS DISTINCT FROM s.c OR t.d IS DISTINCT FROM s.d)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first half of your `MERGE` statement is saying "match records based on `a` and `b`". `source` has two records that have the same value for `a` and `b`, while `target` has no record matching, which means both records will be inserted into `target`.

The second half handles what happens when there is a matching record, and the second time you run the `MERGE` statement, it hits that half. `MERGE` looks at the incoming row from `source`, and finds two matching rows in `target`; without the `HASHBYTES` function, it has no way of knowing which of those `target` rows to update, and therefore throws an error.

When including `HASHBYTES`, it adds an extra criteria to the matching - now, it looks at those two rows in `target`, and determines that neither row satisfy the extra criteria, and so it simply doesn't do any update at all. Note that in this specific case `HASHBYTES` is overkill - you could easily have said `WHEN MATCHED AND CONCAT(t.c, t.d) != CONCAT(s.c, s.d)`.

All that said - I question whether you're really solving your original problem. This approach will not dedupe `source`. You may want to consider cleaning up `source` before doing your `MERGE`.